# Error in table of contents using parts

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, titletoc

I run into an error using `part` from the package `tocloft`. Below is an example which generates such an error:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\titlecontents{chapter}             % Section
  [0em]                             % Left
  {\vspace*{\baselineskip}}         % Above code
  {\bfseries\thecontentslabel\quad} % Numbered format
  {}                                % Numberless format
  {\quad\thecontentspage}           % Filler
  []                                % Separator
\titlecontents*{section} % Section
  [0em]                  % Left
  {\space}               % Above code
  {\thecontentslabel~}   % Numbered format
  {}                     % Numberless format
  {}                     % Filler
  [\space]              % Separator

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{A}
\chapter{A1}
\chapter{A2}
\section{A2A}

\part{B}
\chapter{B1}
\chapter{B2}

\end{document}
```

The error says "LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.". May I know why is this happening and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is an incompatibility between `titletoc` and `tocloft`.

Thus you should remove `tocloft`, or load it *before* `titletoc` if you really need it.